# Can I get dynamic dom In Java?

Tags: javascript, java, php, multithreading, jsoup

```
<div class="chat_list">
    <div class="chat">
        blahblah1
    <div>
    <div class="chat">
        blahblah2
    <div>
    <div class="chat">
        blahblah3
    <div>
    ...
<div>
```

Server(I guess... language is php)/Client(Web Browser) communicate a message each other by js(javascript).

I try to use jsoup. It just parsed only once.

I want to intercept dynamic chat log! 
How can I get dynamic dom?

is it possible using thread&jsoup?

Comment: P.S chat  class is dynamic dom! It is realtime chat  log. I want to parse it

Comment: There is a difference between Java and JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Comment: of course, I know that!
thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into Selenium WebDriver which runs an actual browser and will execute all the Javascript. Since it runs actual browser, you should be able to scrape those 'dynamic' chat.

Reference - http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: Thank your answer!
But how can I check to change dom (added div element)?